# How to read XML sent using XMLHTTP in codebehind file?

Tags: xml, code-behind, xmlhttprequest, c#

I have a javascript code where i am creating an XML Dom and sending (using XMLHTTP ) it to a codebehind page
(server.aspx.cs).How can i read the XML there ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to simply load the InputStream from the Request object into an XmlDocument object

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument postedXml;
    postedXml = new XmlDocument();
    postedXml.Load(Request.InputStream);
```

You can then access the postedXML document as normal.